# 404 error when redirecting to a 403 page with .htaccess?

Tags: html, .htaccess

I receive a 404 problem:

```
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

My .htaccess looks like this. My .htaccess and index.html is within the 'bar' folder:

```
 ErrorDocument 403 /public_html/foo/bar/errorpages/403.html

order deny,allow

deny from all

allow from 123.456
```

---

I also have a .htaccess in my errorpages:

```
order deny,allow
allow from all
```

Am i redirecting it wrong?

**UPDATE**

I have also tried changing the directory to

```
/bar/errorpages/403.html
```

But still same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
order allow, deny
```

instead.

Look at examples [here](http://www.htaccess-guide.com/deny-visitors-by-ip-address/).

Comment: Sorry, that did not do anything.

My .htaccess is in the same folder as my index.html, is that causing conflicts?

Comment: No, it's ok to have them in the same folder.

Comment: Did you restart the Apache service after changing the htaccess file?  I'm not sure if that's necessary; I've had to do that after changing http.conf before.

Comment: Yes, but that does not seem to be the problem for me, any other solutions you may have? this has been bugging me for hours

Comment: You might check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/12456158/2079606; it looks like there was a problem in the httpd.conf file causing the issue.

Comment: Modified as follows. This time I don't get the 404 but it does not show my custom error page?

order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from <removed ip>
ErrorDocument 403 /403.html
<Files 403.html>
allow from all
</Files>